# How to multithread loading partial views?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got a dashboard view that loads up several independent partial views.  Each partial view takes around a quarter of a second to load up (and yes, they probably could be optimized), but I'd like to find a way to multithread the loading of these partial views to make loading even faster.

Right now, in order to render the screen quickly, we start by loading a bare-bones view, with a `<div id="myWidget">` section for each partial view/widget, in which we fill in "Loading data..."  Then, in javascript on each partial view, we make another jQuery call to load the related data.  When that comes back, we replace the original `myWidget` span with the partial view.

I would like all those widgets to work in parallel.  How do you do it?

Comment: That completely depends on exactly what they're doing.

Comment: @SLaks - it's basically a dashboard showing current statistics of various things.  Each partial view loads a graph or some other widget showing the "state of health" of some area under the current user's responsibility.

Comment: It still completely depends on what they're loading.  If it's thread-safe and doesn't use shared state, you can paralellize it.  Use TPL.

Comment: @SLaks - Let's assume it's thread safe.  Can you please give an example of how you would use TPL as an answer?

Comment: That depends on how your calling the code.  Look at the `Parallel` class.

Comment: @SLaks - I've expanded the question to explain how it's working.  Is it possible to parallelize all the jQuery calls somehow?

Comment: what is your actual requirement, to show the widgets all at once or to make single ajax call to fetch the data together?

Comment: You're probably already loading in parallel.  (although session state might defeat that) Look at the network tab.

Comment: @eka - None of the above. Requirement is to minimize wait time for the user, both in terms of starting to paint the screen and final presentation of data.  How we get there is open for discussion.  The Ajax approach is not set in stone; any suggestions for a better way are welcome.

Comment: @SLaks - what "Network" tab?

Comment: @Shaul In your developers tools (hit F12) in IE, Chrome, etc there is a network tab that shows the downloading of the page and the associated resources, such as ajax calls.  This will show you how or if your ajax calls are being made in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a single ajax call, then prepare the data for all widgets. In action method make Async calls to prepare data in parallel. Refer http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4#SampleApp

Then pass the all data to view as model, use different partial views to render each widgets and return the mashup view as response.

On client side, on success of ajax call, replace the entire dashboard/widget area with the data you received as response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your setup is that the browser can only make so many simultaneous calls to the same web server at the same time. So while you can create a ton of ajax requests all at once, generally only 2-10(depending on browser, OS) are gonna be active at a time. The rest sit in a queue until the others complete.

I personally think that all the data that you're loading through the initial ajax requests now should be pre-loaded by the first request(the one that loaded the page, not the first ajax request). Any updates from the client side can then be done individually afterwards.